# Need to know the exact values for sense resistor, resistors in op-amp and power supplies

Tags: operational-amplifier, current-measurement, resistance

[image: circuit]

I am computer scientist and I don't know much about electronics.
In my master work, I have to design a circuit that measure the energy consumption of receiving single tweet from mobile (smartphones). I made a circuit that measure the voltage difference, amplifies it and sends it to ADC.
Kindly have a look at circuit. The problem is that I don't know exactly how much miliOhm  or Ohm resistor should I use.
I know mobile battery operates at 3.7 V. I place the sense resistor if mobile receives any text SMS or tweet. Then it will measure the difference or cost of single tweet in term of voltage

Kindly help me out, or if there is good tutorial then let me know.

Comment: The resistor values are specified in that diagram you have there ...

Comment: The best value of the resistors depends on what is the average and maximum current through the mobile that you want to measure. Do you have any idea how much current the mobile uses when it's not receiving a tweet?

Comment: That said, I think this is a "very difficult" (in the Japanese sense) project. The energy used to actually receive the tweet will probably be much less than the energy used to alert the user the tweet arrived (sound or vibration), and less than the current used to light the screen when the user turns it on to read the tweet.

Comment: Finally, a '741 is a horrible op-amp to use for this purpose. An instrumentation amp may in fact be preferred to an op-amp. Off the top of my head, have a look at the AD8221.

Comment: The other problem is that the current consumption of mobiles is _extremely_ "busrty", so you might want some sort of integration in the current measurement hardware.

Comment: The incremental cost of a tweet is a drop in the bucket compared to the overhead to manage the display power and other background activities which are user & platform dependant. But if you are getting more than 1 tweet a minute, maybe you should aggregate them.

Answer (score 1):

Several points:

If you can make the power source for the "mobile" floating, as you show it being a battery, there is no need for a diff amp.  Declare the low side of the current sense resistor to be the ground of your measuring circuit.  The other side is then a nicely ground-referenced voltage proportional to the supply current.

As someone else already said, a 741 is a crappy opamp for this application, in fact most applications.  If you follow point #1, then you will need something with common mode input range extending to ground, or use a bipolar supply.

The signal you are looking for will likely be tiny compared to the steady current draw.  You therefore will need very good signal to noise ratio.

The current draw when not picking up a tweet probably varies over short times as a function of lots of other unpredictable things going on in the unit.  It is quite possible that these variations are larger than whatever incremental current draw there might be to process a tweet, if there even is one.  Again, this is all saying that the signal to noise ratio will be small.  Quite possibly the signal you want, if it even exists, will be so buried in noise as to be undetectable.